# Jquery progress bar implementation for JSP/Liferay

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, liferay

I'm quite new to JSP/Liferay portlet development and I'm trying to add a progress bar using jQuery, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883101/jsp-progress-bar) but wasn't very specific to how it will be done using AJAX.

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction to help me get started.

thanks.

EDIT:

I used [JSON simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple), and  manage to make some changes but I am getting a bad request(error code 400 when using fire bug) and a 404 not found on my JS

below is my code:

```
public void processAction(
        ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
    throws IOException, PortletException {

//some code here


    this.generateJSON(actionRequest, actionResponse);//manual call the method?

 public void generateJSON(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse)
    throws IOException, PortletException {
        try{
                        //just want to see a progress bar so do static for now...
            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
            obj.put("percent",new Integer(30));
            StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
            obj.writeJSONString(out);
            String jsonText = out.toString();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.print(ex);
        }
        }
    }//end of class
```

JS here

```
    function checkStatus(){
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          //url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/checkStatusServlet',
          url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/generateJSON',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function( data )
          {
            alert(data.statusPercent);  
            var statusPercent = data.percent;
            //Update your jQuery progress bar   
            $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({value: statusPercent});

          }
    });
    //below works and alert is being called...
    /*for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {
         $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({value: i+10});
    }
    alert('got here');
    */
}
```

HTML/JSP

```
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences" %>
<portlet:defineObjects/>
<portlet:renderURL var="resourceUrl"></portlet:renderURL>
<!-- Javascript files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- end of Java script files -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout('checkStatus()',1000);
</script>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't generate JSON in processAction. This method is meant to change the portlet state, but not generate output. The portal-way to accomplish what you need it to use the serveResource method/lifecycle-phase: you get the URL for this from the portal ( < portlet:resourceURL / >). Specifically you shouldn't create them yourself.

An alternative (but not the portal way) is to use a servlet - but in this you don't have the portlet state that you might need.

And you might want to use < portlet:namespace / > to disambiguate your global names - or use proper namespacing - because you can never say how many times your portlet will be placed on a page.

(added spaces to jsp-tags so that they don't get eaten by markup)

Short: Read about resource-serving for portlets, this will most likely solve your underlying problem: With the code you give above you won't be able to access your JSON at all - no matter what you do on the JS side.

Comment: I will, but for now I just used a different langguage ASP.NET/C#. I will learn this. thanks all.

Comment: sometimes you just have to forgo idealism and "just get it done"

Answer (score 1):

The answer really depends on your specific needs. Are you trying to display how much time is actually left for some task, or how much time till a page loads or what?

You could poll from the client and update the progress bar in the browser depending on how much is left to process. A simple jQuery ajax example:

```
function checkStatus
{
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/checkStatusServlet',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function( data )
          {
            var statusPercent = data.statusPercent;

            //Update your jQuery progress bar   
            $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({value: statusPercent });
          }
    });
}
```

Then you can simply poll this function till its done

```
setTimeout('checkStatus()' 1000);
```

Of course you will also need to construct a servlet or struts action or portlet to handle the processing on the server, and return the appropriate status for the task.

EDIT:

Use the [JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java)
From your servlet or action. (code below is from struts2 action)

```
public String checkStatus()
{       
    try 
    {
        Integer percentDone = 50;  //Calculate how much time is left

        JSONObject statusResult = new JSONObject();

        statusResult.put("statusPercent", percentDone);

        //Obtain HttpServletResponse.. 
        //implementation depends on your framework. 
        //PortletResponse should work too.
        PrintWriter out = this.response.getWriter();
        out.write( statusResult.toString(4) );
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {} 
    catch (JSONException e) {}

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to determine how much time it takes for a particular task. basically something like this: http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/06/11/jsp_progressbars.html?page=1 unfortunately I can't make it to work and seems a bit outdated. another question is how would I go about outputing JSON in JSP?

Comment: I have managed to figure out using JSON in Java but I still can't get this to work..

Comment: see my edit above..I used another JSON library... and get no errors/exceptions when I debug  but I still can't get a progress bar to appear on a page