# jquery progress bar with servlet without $.ajax

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, progress-bar, return-value

**Html**

```
<body>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
</body>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: 5 });
        });
```

and

**In NewServlet**

```
int percentage=5;
//Code Snippet; 
percentage=25; //at line# 200
//Code Snippet; 
percentage=50; //at line# 1004
//Code Snippet; 
percentage=75; //at line# 5006
//Code Snippet; 
percentage=100; //at line# 7000
//Code Snippet;
```

How can I update these values (percentage) from servlet to jauery,  as particular line of code execute and suddenly update the value of progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can try to manually flush out your percentage value and update the value in jQuery progressbar plugin.

I am not sure what exactly your intention of using the progress bar is. Usually, progress bar is good in the cases where user needs to upload a file, execute timed tasks, etc.

You might want to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5883497/786796), which I think is quite insightful.

Comment: Yes! I want to manually flush out percentage. Suppose! I am generating pdf from .jrxml and then emailing this pdf on the same page(unlimited files can be attach with email). It takes 5-7 seconds. when Pdf is generated , then I manually flush out percentage 50% and as email sent, then manually flush out percentage 100%. This is my need.